# SelectRow with Checkbox in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview, datagrid

I have a Datagrid with a CheckBox column. I need to select more than one row from this datagrid and get the SelectedRows to another form. What I need is that when I check the checkboxes all the checked rows must still selected (blue hightlight) until I pass them to the another form. I can do it now, but just for one row, the selected one with this code

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                      
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            table.Columns.Add(column.Name, typeof(string)); //tipo cell??
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
        {
           table.Rows.Add();

            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                table.Rows[i][j] = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Cells[j].Value;
                fph.dataGridView1.DataSource = table; //DATAGRID DO FORM PH 
            }
        }
    }
```

thank you all!

Comment: Do you have MultiSelect on?

Comment: Is there DataGrid AND DataGridView in your application or only the DataGridView? If it is the latter case, please avoid shortening it to DataGrid, because DataGrid is the name of another (almost deprecated) .NET component

Comment: @TaW - Yes i have it on!

Comment: @SauliusŠimčikas - OK! Thank you and sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking one an item selects it and deselets all others. **This is standard behaviour.** The obvious way to go within the GUI standards is to educate your users to press **control** if they don't want to lose their current selection, just like they have to anywhere else in the system.

If you don't like that, you will have either find some weird trick or on each CellMouseDown check if this is the Checkbox column and then store the selected rows and restore the selection on CellMouseUp. (or something like this, no time here to test this for you..)

Comment: I'm understanding, like a "check all items" then the users deselects the others. I think that will be the way I'll choose too! Thank you Mr. TaW

Answer (score 1):

I know its a very old question but there is no other answer available that I could find.

The trick to making this work is to save the DataGridView.SelectedRows on the CellMouse**UP** event.
Then use the CellContentChanged event or similar to actually do something with that selection.

So the user makes a multiple selection. As they release the mouse while making this selection it is saved. Then they go to click a checkbox or something, which clears the dgv selection to only one row. But you use the saved selection to actually make the changes. The new, single row, selection is only saved when they release the mouse, after the changes have been made.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).